# Webpack Dependency Build Error - Package Upgrade

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am receiving this error while running npm install in a project with webpack (I am running npm install after having removed the node_modules directory because of errors encountered while building). I am a little confused on what I need to upgrade exactly based on this error. Webpack or css-loader?

```
 While resolving: client@1.0.0
 Found: webpack@2.7.0
 node_modules/webpack
 dev webpack@"^2.7.0" from the root project

 Could not resolve dependency:
 peer webpack@"^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from css-loader@3.6.0
 node_modules/css-loader
 dev css-loader@"^3.1.0" from the root project
```

My package.js file contains "css-loader": "^3.1.0" and "webpack": "^2.7.0"

Thank you. J

Comment: `css-loader` has a dependency on `webpack` v4 or v5

Comment: Thank you @Phil But I have webpack 2.7.0 installed, explaining why I do not understand why there is a dependency on v4 or v5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are setting "webpack": "^2.7.0" means you want the version 2.7.0 or a newer minor or patch version (2.7.1, 2.8.0, etc) but not a version that changes the major version (example 3.0.0).

Now, the css-loader package requires webpack to be at least major version 4.

Solution: Update webpack.

More information in https://semver.org/ and [this medium post](https://medium.com/@Hardy2151/caret-and-tilde-in-package-json-57f1cbbe347b)

Comment: Thank you @Nat I understand your explanation. However, I have css-loader 3.1.0 installed and not 3.6.0 (according to my package.json file). Why is it referring to this last version?

Comment: In fact, you have 3.6.0 installed, because you are setting "css-loader": "^3.1.0" (note the ^) in your package.json, if you don't want to change the minor version, set "css-loader": "~3.1.0" instead. Check out the complementary links I sent you ;)